# Crontab job doesn't create db backups with `mysqldump` command

Tags: crontab, vps, mysqldump

When I type in my VPS:

```
$ mysqldump --opt --user=root --password=myPass dbName>/home/myuser/dbName.sql
```

it works and makes a backup of my dbName, but if I do it from a crontab job, it creates an empty backup. What could I be dong wrong?

In my crontab job I put:

```
* */24 * * * sh /root/backup.sh
```

and I put the `mysqldump` command inside.

There are the next differences between output of `env` command executed like a crontab job and like a command executed with ssh connection logged as root:

`env` in crontab job:

```
MAILTO=xxxx@gmail.com
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

`env` in the console logged as root:

```
 SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
SSH_CLIENT=xxx.xx.xx.xxx xxxxx xx
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PWD=/home/myuser
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=xxx.xx.xx.xxx xxxxx xxx.xx.xxx.xx xx
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: You mentioned that you ran the mysqldump command directly, but, did you try "sh /root/backup.sh" manually from the ssh shell (not in the cron)?

Comment: Thanks, but it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is very simply. Leaving the `$` symbol from `mysqldump` command in `/root/backup.sql` all works fine. What a stupid mistake!!

Answer (score 2):

You could be missing environment variable(s) in the `cron` environment. 
Put a command like

```
env > /…/cron_env.txt
```

into your `backup.sh`,
and compare the output to that of an `env` that you run when you’re logged in.

Also, you might try adding `2> /…/mysqldump_error.txt` to your `mysqldump` command,
to capture the error messages.

Comment: I've found the solution thanks to you. It was the `$` symbol!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your crontab entry is not configured correctly.  You may have success using:

```
* */24 * * * root /root/backup.sh
```